# don't know how to convert properly

Tags: c#, char, int

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(subjectsLabel1.Text);
int b = int.Parse(internetLabel1.Text);
int total = a+b;
label1.Text = total.ToString();
```

the error "Input string was not in a correct format." keeps poping out.
I tried to convert using the "int.parse" and the "convert.toint32" syntax but the same error keeps showing up.

*the values in the subjectsLabel1 and internetlabel1 would be coming from the database (which was done in visual studio) w/ datatype varchar(10).

Comment: Can you show us the one sample value that your code is failing for?

Comment: What values do you have for `subjectsLabel1.Text` and `internetLabel1.Text`?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way you do the conversion. It's just that the values you are trying to convert are not legal.

Comment: The values that was stored in subjectsLabel1 and internetLabel1 are simple numbers like 42, 50 etc. what i think is since that it came from the database with a datatype varchar(10), it is looking for 10 characters. But since there are only 2 characters for 40, the error keeps poping out.

Comment: @erwinmendoza: the `var` in the start of `varchar(10)` is for 'variable', meaning it can have up to 10 characters, it doesn't have to have 10.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the way you are parsing those string values to integers. It's just that their value doesn't represent a valid integer so it cannot be parsed and an exception is thrown. You could use the [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) method to handle gracefully this case:

```
int a;
int b;
if (!int.TryParse(subjectsLabel1.Text, out a))
{
    MessageBox.Show("please enter a valid integer in subjectsLabel1");
} 
else if (!int.TryParse(internetLabel1.Text, out b))
{
    MessageBox.Show("please enter a valid integer in internetLabel1");
}
else
{
    // the parsing went fine => we could safely use the a and b variables here
    int total = a + b;
    label1.Text = total.ToString();
}
```

Comment: the messagebox "please enter a valid integer in subjectsLabel1" show up so it didn't compute. I had already tested the int.tryparse before but it still didn't work.

Comment: @erwin mendoza, well in this case you will have to enter a valid integer value for `subjectsLabel1.Text`. If it contains null, empty string or an invalid integer the conversion will always fail. Also it will fail if you entered some decimal value like "1.75". In this case you need to use `decimal.Parse` and store the result into a decimal variable. Or float. Or double. It will depend on the value you are trying to store.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure the user is giving you a legal Int32 value to convert you can use:

```
int result;

if (!int.TryParse(subjectsLabel.Text, out result))
{
 ShowAMessageToTheUser();
}
else
{
 UseResult();
}
```

Using TryParse won't trow an exception when you try to parse a string. Instead it will return false and the out parameter is not valid to use.

Answer (score 0):

You Cannot convert to Int32 if the string contains a decimal pointor its not a valid integer .Check

```
string test = "15.00"
int testasint = Convert.ToInt32(test); //THIS WILL FAIL!!!
```

Because Int32 does not support decimals. If you need to use decimals, use Float or Double.

So in this situation you can use

```
int.TryParse
```

also